# Required disk space miscalculation preventing progress

Tags: install4j

It seems that there is a mismatch between the disk space displayed in the GUI in MB and the actual space interpreted by the installer in KB.

The bug so far is being reproduced on RHEL 6.5 64b.

[image: Bug repro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer requires a 10% safety margin that may be used by temporary files or for the actually larger amount of required disk space for small files.

That safety margin was not included in the displayed value on the "Installation location" screen. This will be fixed in install4j 6.0.2.